# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted

Tags: python, pyqt, garbage-collection, qthread

`Hi everybody!
I've wrote a GUI python application with PyQt5. The application is started with 'ui_loader.py' file as shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from controllers.login_window_controller import LoginWindowController


def login_window_started():
    login_window = LoginWindowController(
        parent=None,
        on_completion=login_window_closed,
        mode=LoginWindowController.OpeningMode.VIEW
    )
    login_window.show()

    login_window.window_started()


def login_window_closed():
    print("login_window_closed from load_ui")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # app.setStyle("Fusion")
    login_window_started()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After clicking some buttons and pro`your text`ceeding through the app my code reaches to the below function:

```
def compare_clicked(self):
    check_passed = self.check_loaded_file()
    if check_passed:
        self.disable_widgets()
        self.main_w.spinner_request.emit(self.updaterTabComparePushButton, "Comparing", False)
        self.main_w.compare_request.emit(self)
```

The `self.main_w.compare_request.emit(self)` triggers a worker (running on another QThread) and the worker returns the result to the function below:

```
def compare_completed(self, result: bool):
    self.enable_widgets()

    if not result or not self.pre_populate_table():
        self.reset()
        return

    self.populate_table()
```

The program crashes at `self.enable_widgets()` and i got the following error:

"RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted"

I've search a lot but i couldn't find a solution, I would be pleased if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

I think the problem is around garbage collector but i don't know how to solve it.`

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].